# SurfaceView set zoom in and out

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I am working on live streaming application using webrtc, in this I have to apply the zoom in and zoom out functionality on surface view. On GLSurfaceView I am rendering the screen video shared by the other peer. Please if anyone could help about this.

Comment: Have you solved this and implemented zoom in your app?

Comment: No I have tried a lot but not got the solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the capability of building webrtc yourself, you can actually go into the android code and add the zoom functionality.